# How can I determine a labels index inside an event.

Tags: c#, controls

I have a `List` of labels which represent bars of a dynamically created mesh grid as part of a little game. The labels in question are the elements in red in the picture below.

[image]

I have two loops where each pass will create one of the labels. First loop creates the vertical labels where the other creates the horizontal.

```
// Build the next grid unit
lblGridUnit = new Label
{
    Location = new Point(CurrentX, CurrentY),
    BackColor = Color.Red,
    AutoSize = false,
    // The unit will be the size and width as defined by variables. Since this units are vertical the width and height are reversed. 
    Size = new Size { Width = gridUnitHeight, Height = gridUnitWidth },
    Text = ""
};

lblGridUnit.Click += new EventHandler ( label_Click);

// Add the label the list and attach it to the form
gridUnits.Add(lblGridUnit);
ParentForm.Controls.Add(lblGridUnit);
```

I have a *really* basic event `label_Click` that I am using for testing.

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;

    if (clickedLabel != null)
    {
        clickedLabel.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Null");
    }
}
```

I can interact with specific labels using the event and I can also find a specific label by using the list `gridUnits`. Example being: `GameBoard.GridUnits[5].BackColor = Color.Blue;`.

Issue is that I made the list so that I could use the index of a particular label to know where it is one the grid and determine neighboring grid units. How can I get the event to know its index in the `List`?

I have not named any of my controls so I suppose I could name them with a numerical suffix but that seems like kludge so wondering if there is another option. Literally never coded c# until a couple of days ago.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah. That would work just fine. So populate that property with the index as I build them. Kinda makes the List redundant so I guess I would not even need it. Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: How about using `lblGridUnit .Name` to determine index of each `Label`?

Comment: @HariPrasad I had mentioned that as a possibility but using `tag` seems like a simpler approach then trying to parse a integer out of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls have [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property designed for this purpose - to store arbitrary piece of data that lets you map control to your model either directly or by some id/name.

Since you already creating all labels with code setting `Tag` to grid index or some other more convenient value is trivial.

Note that since `Tag` is of type `object` you need to cast it to correct type of your data. If having very general click handler prefer `target.Tag as MyType` to `(MyType)target.Tag)` as you can check for null when using `as`.

Comment: I had created my own user control with an index property. No need since Tag already existed. Thanks for pointing this out for me.